# Writing the right sax code

Tags: matlab-coder

i wrote a SAX(symbolic aggregate approximation) classification code using synthetic control training and testing data but it never gives me the right accuracy( i got 0.2 error and the real was 0.02 error) using window_size = 16 and alphabet = 10 . I want to know what is the right code to do so.